# Generate http error from python3 requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, http-error

I have a  simple long poll thing using `python3` and the `requests` package. It currently looks something like:

```
def longpoll():
    session = requests.Session()
    while True:
        try:
            fetched = session.get(MyURL)
            input = base64.b64decode(fetched.content)
            output = process(data) 
            session.put(MyURL, data=base64.b64encode(response))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            time.sleep(10)
```

There is a case where instead of `process`ing the input and `put`ing the result, I'd like to raise an http error. Is there a simple way to do this from the high level `Session` interface? Or do I have to drill down to use the lower level objects?

Comment: Do you have control over the remote server as well?

Comment: Yes I have control of the remote server as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since You have control over the server you may want to reverse the 2nd call

Here is an example using bottle to recive the 2nd poll

```
def longpoll():
    session = requests.Session()
    while True: #I'm guessing that the server does not care that we call him a lot of times ...
        try: 
            session.post(MyURL, {"ip_address": my_ip_address}) # request work or I'm alive
            #input = base64.b64decode(fetched.content)
            #output = process(data) 
            #session.put(MyURL, data=base64.b64encode(response))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            time.sleep(10)

@bottle.post("/process") 
def process_new_work():
    data = bottle.request.json()
    output = process(data) #if an error is thrown an HTTP error will be returned by the framework
    return output
```

This way the server will get the output or an bad HTTP status